# output all mailboxes with inbox rules

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to get a list of all Exchange mailboxes that have inbox rules. I am able to get a list of all mailboxes and a count of how many rules each mailbox has. I am trying to skip or have no output for mailboxes with zero rules.

```
$mailboxes = get-mailbox
foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxes) {

Write-Output $mailbox.id,((Get-InboxRule -Mailbox $mailbox.id)| Measure-Object | select count)

}
```

Current code outputs:
User1
0
User2
11
User3
0
User4
1
User5
0
etc....

I am looking to only output user's who have inbox rules.

Thanks-

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env powershell
get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited  |
ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output -Message ('Checking {0}...' -f $_.alias) -Verbose
    $inboxrule = get-inboxrule -Mailbox $_.alias  
    if ($inboxrule) {
        foreach($rule in $inboxrule){
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            Mailbox         = $_.alias
            ## you could uncomment this if you wanted more information
            ##Rulename        = $rule.name
            ##Rulepriority    = $rule.priority
            ##Ruledescription = $rule.description
        }
    }
    }
} | 
Export-csv -Path "$env:userprofile/desktop/export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This should give you a list of just the users who have rules.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your expected is but to answer *how to exclude those mailboxes with no inbox rules*:

```
foreach($mailbox in Get-Mailbox) {
    $ibxrules = @(Get-InboxRule $mailbox.Id).Count
    if($ibxrules -eq 0) {
        continue
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        MailboxId  = $mailbox.Id
        InboxRules = $ibxrules
    }
}
```

To explain the use of [`@(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--) around `Get-InboxRule`, this is to ensure the output is always an array, and this also ensures we can always get a `.Count` out of it.

Comment: Thanks for your time in posting to my question. Unfortunately neither options give me what I am looking for. The output I am looking for is like this Username number of inbox rules (jsmith 12). If the mailbox has no inbox rules then skip it or have no output for it. I was thinking the code from Santiago was what I needed but I get the operation couldn't be performed because "OU\Users\User" couldn't be found. I am not sure if that is because I am  using pssession to remote to exchange or not.